# Kibana/Elastic Regex Query Returns No Results

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, logstash, kibana

We have Logstash receiving syslog files and then storing these in an Elasticsearch index.

We are trying to query this index with Kibana to find some particular information but we cannot get the regex queries to work.

The log date we are trying to search within is below.

- Field name = message
- Field type = keyword

> <14>1 2018-05-02T13:53:48.079000Z snrvro04 vco - - [liagent@6876
>   anctoken="" component="WorkflowManagementServiceImpl" context=""
>   filepath="/var/log/vco/app-server/integration-server.log"
>   instanceid="6a6dbf1d-2f72-45db-ab57-04b84aa97b90"
>   log_message="Workflow 'Get ID of
>   Workflow/8f59ca66-7472-4efa-ac5f-dfc34059c5f1' updated (with
>   content)." priority="INFO" product="vro" token="" user="" wfid=""
>   wfname="" wfstack=""] 2018-05-02 13:53:48.079+0000 vco:
>   [component="WorkflowManagementServiceImpl" priority="INFO"
>   thread="https-jsse-nio-0.0.0.0-8281-exec-7" user="" context=""
>   token="" wfid="" wfname="" anctoken="" wfstack=""
>   instanceid="6a6dbf1d-2f72-45db-ab57-04b84aa97b90"] Workflow 'Get ID of
>   Workflow/8f59ca66-7472-4efa-ac5f-dfc34059c5f1' updated (with content).

The information we are trying to search for is:

> component="WorkflowManagementServiceImpl"

AND more importantly:

> Workflow 'Get ID of Workflow/8f59ca66-7472-4efa-ac5f-dfc34059c5f1'

The top criteria should always be the same, but the Workflow name and ID will change. The only part that remains the same within this bit of text is **Workflow '** and the final **'**

We are currently trying our queries against the Workflow name and ID to see if we can match on that, but our queries return no results.

The regex we currently have is as follows, and we have tried numerous alternatives.

```
/(?<=Workflow '.*\/)(.*')/
```

If we run the search *** Workflow *** (wildcard, without the spaces) - it returns everything with the word Workflow as expected.

If we run the search **Workflow** we get no results.

If anyone can provide pointers towards where we are going wrong, or getting confused, that would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Try `Workflow *'[^'/]*/([^']*)'`. You need Group 1 value.

Comment: Thanks @wiktor-stribiżew. Tried that, along with a few other alternatives. I have had to escape the /'s in some areas otherwise its not accepted;

`Workflow\/* /'[^'\/]*\/([^']*)'/ *updated` (highlights only the words Workflow and updated)

`/'[^'\/]*\/([^']*)'/` (returns no results in Kibana)

I have also changed the index so the message field is both text and keyword

`"message": {
   "type": "text",
      "fields": {
         "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
         }
      }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this by using Grok filters in Logstash to organise/clean the data before it hits the Elasticsearch Indexes, then we were able to search successfully within Kibana.